# How to get Google to convert (for example) bytes to gigabytes

Tags: google-search

I **know** I have done it in the past accidentally. Maybe this was a feature that has since been turned off?

If someone knows, I would appreciate the tip. Some documentation of the exact syntax would be *very* helpful as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Works fine for me](http://www.google.com/search?q=2000+bytes+in+gigabytes).

Comment: Ah. I tried "2000b to GB". Thanks sir. Documentation: http://www.google.com/intl/en/help/features.html#unit

Answer (score 2):

Google the following: 1 byte to gigabytes